# Populate Azure AD User Properties From CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, azure-active-directory, import-csv

I am modifying batches of user properties based on the contents of a .csv. the csv contains an ObjectID which I use to identify a specific user and the value I want the property set to. (see Below)

```
ObjectID,Property2,Property3
1,John,smith
2,Jane,Doe
```

The Issue I am experiencing is "the property 'Property2' cannot be found on this object." I get a similar error for all the variables I am trying to set. I feel I am missing something really simple, but I simply don't know what it is. My code can be found below. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$Csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\1\2\3\4\Example.Csv" |ForEach-Object {
    $User.ObjectID = $Csv | Select ObjectID
    $User.Property2 = $Csv | Select Property2
    $User.Property3 = $Csv | Select Property3

    Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID $User.ObjectID -Property3 $User.Property3 -Property2 $User.Property2
}
```

Comment: Replace the 3 lines with `$user = $_` and it will work :-)

Comment: Just do `Import-Csv -Path "C:\1\2\3\4\Example.Csv" | ForEach-Object {Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.ObjectID -Property3 $_.Property3 -Property2 $_.Property2}`

Comment: Ok, So I believe that corrects that issue. Can you please tell me what that is? I've never seen it before.

Comment: You mean the `$_` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#_) ?

Comment: yes, That is entirely new to me, I'll have to read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bpengu

The other approach in addition to Theo had mentioned using the **Automatic variable**. The concept is almost same as above it iterates through each object (each row).

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\1\2\3\4\Example.Csv"
foreach ($user in $users)
{
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user.ObjectID -Property3 $user.Property3 -Property2 $user.Property2
}
```